# Installing sleuth using Bioconductor, error where the path is not writable?

Tags: bioconductor

I'm having trouble installing sleuth into R studio. I have already tried troubleshooting using the suggested methods in a stockoverflow titled "installation path not writable R, unable to update packages" (link: [installation path not writable R, unable to update packages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41839214/installation-path-not-writable-r-unable-to-update-packages)). I keep getting the following error.

Error Message:

```
Bioconductor version 3.10 (BiocManager 1.30.10), R 3.6.1 (2019-07-05)
Installation path not writeable, unable to update packages: boot, class, foreign, KernSmooth, lattice,
  MASS, Matrix, mgcv, nlme, nnet
Old packages: 'isoband', 'purrr', 'RcppArmadillo', 'RCurl', 'reshape2', 'survival'
Update all/some/none? [a/s/n]: 
BiocManager::install("devtools")    # only if devtools not yet installed
Update all/some/none? [a/s/n]: 
BiocManager::install("pachterlab/sleuth")
Update all/some/none? [a/s/n]:
```

When I type in this code:

```r
if (!requireNamespace("BiocManager", quietly = TRUE))
    install.packages("BiocManager")
BiocManager::install()
BiocManager::install("devtools")    # only if devtools not yet installed
BiocManager::install("pachterlab/sleuth")
```

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50364335/11801854) might be helpful.

It looks like the offending packages (`boot`, `class`, `foreign`, etc.) are installed in a location where you do not have writing permissions for.

In principle, the `sleuth` package should have been installed, despite the error messages (you can check this by running `library(sleuth)` in an R console). However, to avoid having these errors each time you try installing a (BioConductor) package, I would recommend to re-install those offending packages in a directory where you have writing access to. Depending on your OS this can be in different locations.

I found [this guide](https://rstats.wtf/maintaining-r.html#how-to-transfer-your-library-when-updating-r) particularly useful to maintain R packages.

In short (all commands are run in R):

1. Remove the packages mentioned in the error message with `remove.packages()`, if `sleuth` was installed, remove it as well, we will install it again later in a more maintainable way
2. In R, check the output of `Sys.getenv("R_LIBS_USER")`, this should normally be a directory path under your home directory
3. It's likely that the `R_LIBS_USER` directory does not yet exist, create it with `dir.create(Sys.getenv("R_LIBS_USER"))`
4. **Restart R** (in RStudio, you can do *Session* → *Restart R*
5. Check the output of `.libPaths()`, the first element should now be the directory you just created (i.e. the same as `Sys.getenv("R_LIBS_USER")`), **this is now the default directory where R packages will be installed**
6. Install `sleuth` again with `BiocManager::install("pachterlab/sleuth")`, this should normally also install all dependencies. If not you might have to install them separately.

Hope this helps!