# Error: Bioconductor version '3.13' requires R version '4.1' (R version 4.0.2)

Tags: r, ubuntu, bioconductor

I found 'similar' questions from other users but none of the answers worked. I am trying to install these packages among others:

```
if (!require("BiocManager"))
  install.packages("BiocManager")
BiocManager::install("maEndToEnd", version = "devel") 

if (!require("BiocManager"))
  install.packages("BiocManager")
BiocManager::install("ArrayExpress")
----------------------------------------------------------
Error: Bioconductor version '3.13' requires R version '4.1'
```

My R version 4.0.2, my OS is Ubuntu 20.10
I thought that maybe I could:

a) Change my R version (I did not find for ubuntu R version 4.1)

b) Change my Bioconductor version. For that reason I executed:

```
if (!requireNamespace("BiocManager", quietly = TRUE))
    install.packages("BiocManager")
BiocManager::install(version = "3.12")
------------------------------------------------------
Error in packageVersion("BiocManager") : 
  there is no package called ‘BiocManager’
```

```
install("BiocManager")
------------------------------
Error: Can't find 'BiocManager'
´´´

I also tried so many things that I believe I just made worse the situation by eliminating packages from other libraries:  
/usr/lib/R/site-library 
/home/usr_name/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.0
```

This are the packages directories I currently have:

```
library()
------------------------------------
 Packages in library ‘/usr/lib/R/site-library’:

askpass                    
assertthat                
backports              
base64enc                 
BH                    
Metapackage
bit                       
bit64                     
bitops                    
blob                       
brew                      
callr                     
cli                       
cliapp                  
clipr                      
colorspace                
and
                 
etc...

Packages in library ‘/usr/lib/R/library’:  

base 
boot
for

class
cluster
Extended

etc ...
```

How may I proceed? As you can tell I am  a beginner in everything related to informatics. Any detail would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless you really need a particular version of a BioConductor package, you don't need to specify `version`. Try the following [standard approach](http://www.modernstatisticswithr.com/advancedchapter.html#alternative-repositories) and see if that works:

```
install.packages("BiocManager")
library(BiocManager)
install() # Install BioConductor core packages
install("maEndToEnd")
install("ArrayExpress")
```

Comment: BiocManager was installed, the other commands give me errors:

Comment: install()  --> The downloaded source packages are in: ‘/tmp/Rtmpn41lQy/downloaded_packages’   Installation path not writeable, unable to update packages: backports, BH, bit, bit64, callr,  etc...

Comment: install("maEndToEnd") --> DONE (clusterProfiler)
ERROR: dependencies ‘oligoClasses’, ‘ArrayExpress’, ‘pd.hugene.1.0.st.v1’, ‘oligo’, ‘arrayQualityMetrics’ are not available for package ‘maEndToEnd’
* removing ‘/home/mrgerry/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.0/maEndToEnd’    The downloaded source packages are in
‘/tmp/Rtmpn41lQy/downloaded_packages’
Installation path not writeable, unable to update packages: backports, BH, bit, bit64,

Comment: install("ArrayExpress") --> Installing package(s) 'ArrayExpress'
also installing the dependencies ‘RCurl’, ‘GenomeInfoDb’, ‘MatrixGenerics’, ‘DelayedArray’, ‘GenomicRanges’, ‘SummarizedExperiment’, ‘oligoClasses’, ‘oligo’
* installing *source* package ‘RCurl’ ...
** package ‘RCurl’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** using staged installation
checking for curl-config... no
Cannot find curl-config
ERROR: configuration failed for package ‘RCurl’
* removing ‘/home/usr_name/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.0/RCurl’
* installing *source* package ‘MatrixGenerics’ ...

Comment: ERROR: lazy loading failed for package ‘MatrixGenerics’
* removing ‘/home/usr_name/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.0/MatrixGenerics’
{  more errors with the same nature }
The downloaded source packages are in
‘/tmp/Rtmpn41lQy/downloaded_packages’
Installation path not writeable, unable to update packages: backports, BH, bit

Comment: @Gero In that case, please have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41839214/installation-path-not-writable-r-unable-to-update-packages

Answer (score 2):

'R-4.1' is what current R-devel will become; R-devel is usually installed from source on linux platforms, but is conveniently available as rocker https://hub.docker.com/r/rocker/r-devel/ and Bioconductor https://hub.docker.com/r/bioconductor/bioconductor_docker/tags (look for the 'devel' tag) docker images.

The report about

```
if (!requireNamespace("BiocManager", quietly = TRUE))
    install.packages("BiocManager")
BiocManager::install(version = "3.12")
------------------------------------------------------
Error in packageVersion("BiocManager") : 
  there is no package called ‘BiocManager’
```

looks incomplete. What happens with

```
if (!requireNamespace("BiocManager", quietly = TRUE))
    install.packages("BiocManager")
```

? It should install (successfully) BiocManager, and `packageVersion("BiocManager")` should report a version. Perhaps it would help to start a new session?

For what it's worth, here's the 'version string' that reports 'R under development' but also version 4.1.0

```
> R.version
               _
platform       x86_64-apple-darwin17.7.0
arch           x86_64
os             darwin17.7.0
system         x86_64, darwin17.7.0
status         Under development (unstable)
major          4
minor          1.0
year           2021
month          02
day            10
svn rev        79979
language       R
version.string R Under development (unstable) (2021-02-10 r79979)
nickname       Unsuffered Consequences
```