# Installing Bioconductor packages

Tags: r, ubuntu, installation, bioconductor

I have installed R(3.4.0) on my ubuntu. I would like to use EdgeR package. I tried to follow the installation instruction available on Bioconductor website to install Bioconductor packages.

I used the following commands in R:

```
    source("https://bioconductor.org/biocLite.R")
    biocLite()
```

but I am getting the following error:

```
    BioC_mirror: https://bioconductor.org
    Using Bioconductor 3.5 (BiocInstaller 1.26.0), R 3.4.0 (2017-04-21).
    installation path not writeable, unable to update packages: spatial
```

I am new to linux and can not understand how to fix the error.

Does any body have any idea how can I fix the issue.

Comment: This might be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28547511/3926543

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I read that before but I could not implement what they were saying.

Answer (score 3):

You can also use *`devtools`* :

```
devtools::install_bioc("edgeR")
```

Answer (score -1):

You can try http:// if https:// URLs are not supported

```
source("http://www.bioconductor.org/biocLite.R")
biocLite("edgeR")
```